# C++ variadic templates pack into std::array and unpack

Tags: c++, templates

I want to pack variables in an array and then unpack using an interface like this

```
int x; float y; double z;
auto data = PackArray(x, y, z); // serializes without padding

...

int x; float y; double z;
UnpackArray(data, x, y, z); // copies data from the array to x, y, z
```

I tried

```
template<class... T>
constexpr size_t SumOfSizeofs(const T&...)
{
    return (sizeof(T) + ...);
}

// Creates array of u8 with size = sum(sizeofs)
template <class A, class ...Rest>
auto PackArray(A& a, Rest&... rest)
{
    return std::array<u8, SumOfSizeofs(a, rest...)>; // doesn't work
}

template <class Array, class...Rest>
auto UnpackArray(Array& array, Rest&... rest)
{
    // iterates through sizeof each element, copying to its new buffer from the array
}
```

If there was an `std::packed_tuple` it would be great... :(
I'm bad with template syntax, help?

Comment: `return std::array<u8, SumOfSizeofs(a, rest...)>{}` would compile :). What doesn't work? Do you need advise on how to `memcpy` args into said array?

Comment: I got error C2975: '_Size': invalid template argument for 'std::array', expected compile-time constant expression

Comment: And I also need help implementing the Unpack function :P

Comment: Sure, why not :) See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my go at it:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <class... T>
[[nodiscard]] auto PackArray(T&&... args) {
  static_assert(
      (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>> && ...),
      "Packing requires trivial-copying");
  std::array<std::byte, (sizeof(T) + ... + 0)> data;
  std::size_t offet = 0;
  (std::memcpy(data.data() + (offet += sizeof(args)) - sizeof(args),
               std::addressof(args), sizeof(args)), ...);
  return data;
}

template <std::size_t sz, class... T>
auto UnpackArray(std::array<std::byte, sz> const& data, T&... args) {
  static_assert(sz == (sizeof(T) + ... + 0), "Mismatch");
  static_assert(
      (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>> && ...),
      "UnPacking requires trivial-copying");
  std::size_t offet = 0;
  (std::memcpy(std::addressof(args),
               data.data() + (offet += sizeof(args)) - sizeof(args),
               sizeof(args)), ...);
}

int main() {
  int x = 42;
  float y = 3.14f;
  double z = 2.72;
  auto data = PackArray(x, y, z);  // serializes without padding

  int x1;
  float y1;
  double z1;
  UnpackArray(data, x1, y1, z1);

  std::printf("%d, %.2f, %.2f", x1, y1, z1);
}
```

Note the use of [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) to avoid problems with objects overloading `operator&`.

Comment: Is that + 0 required? It seems to compile fine without it

Comment: @user pass 0 arguments and it is needed

Comment: How about a `static_assert((std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> && ...))`?

Comment: @aschepler That is a great idea! I added that in and used `remove_reference_t` because references cause trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Here is complete code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string.h>


template <class... Args>
constexpr auto PackArray(const Args&... args)
{
    std::array<uint8_t, (0 + ... + sizeof(Args))> arr;

    size_t packPos = 0;
    auto pack = [&packPos, &arr](const auto& arg) {
         memcpy(arr.data() + packPos, &arg, sizeof(arg));
         packPos += sizeof(arg);
    };
    (pack(args), ...);
    return arr;
}

template <size_t sz, class... Args>
constexpr void UnpackArray(std::array<uint8_t, sz> arr, Args&... args)
{
    static_assert(arr.size() == (... + sizeof(Args)), "Mistmatched packed array size");
    size_t packPos = 0;
    auto unpack = [&packPos, &arr](auto& arg) {
         memcpy(&arg, arr.data() + packPos, sizeof(arg));
         packPos += sizeof(arg);
    };
    (unpack(args),...);
}

auto arr = PackArray(10, 1.0, nullptr);

int a;
double b;
void* c;

void foo() {
    UnpackArray(arr, a, b, c);
}
```

It is a bit tailored to the use case I had in mind, so if it lacks anything you'd want to see, let me know. Also, instead of passing arguments to unpack, I could make it returning a tuple, allowing callers to enjoy structured binding syntax, but you didn't have it in your original code, so I didn't put it there either.

Last, but not the least, you might want to pepper-spray the code with asserts on triviality of the types.

Comment: Could use a fold expression with `,` instead of the old-school array trick (`int pleasePack[] = {pack(args)...};`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I was not sure how to fold with `memcpy`. Now I feel challenged, let me see if I can do this! :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat looked at it, and quickly realized I feel my version to be more readable than anything I might come up with.

Comment: Try `(pack(args),...);` and `(unpack(args),...);` instead of the "throwaway" array `...` stuff.

Comment: ^ That's what I was suggesting.

Comment: You can't use `memcpy` in a `constexpr` function. This function will never produce a constexpr result. Better remove that.

Comment: And you're `memcpy`ing `nullptr_t` to `void*`. I am not sure this is allowed.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I just mark functions constexpr if it itself can be constexpr. Who knows, may be in future standard memcpy() will be marked constexpr? The code is future proof this way. Didn't quite get your beef with `nullptr_t`.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont so simple! Will edit.

Comment: `nullptr_t` is implicitly *convertible* to any pointer. But `memcpy`ing is not a conversion, it's type-punning. I am not 100% sure, but I would guess that's not allowed. You could use `(void*)nullptr` as an easy fix.

Comment: Comma-fold execute also works with void; remove `return 1;`.  Also if you add `0` to size sums, your code supports empty arg packs.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, yep, both are valid points.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I am not sure I understand what you are saying. memcpy is not punning anything, it performs bit-wise copy. I am pretty sure you are misunderstanding this code.

Comment: @SergeyA is it guaranteed that bitwise copying `nullptr` to a pointer will result in a null pointer? Is it even guaranteed that `sizeof(nullptr) == sizeof(void*)`?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili well, you brought the point of it being not allowed, so I believe, the onus is on you to prove this point. I am 100% certain it will work everywhere, otherwise, it would counterintuitively break tremendous amount of code.

Comment: @SergeyA hmm. How about this https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e3rYsa ? As you can see memcpy didn't do the same thing as assignment in this case.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili how about not mixing regular pointers and pointers-to-members? https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hbj651

Comment: pointer-to-members was just an easy example I knew didn't work that way. To be clear, I am not saying you're wrong. I am just saying `memcpy`ing between unrelated types like that is kind of shady.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili your example has nothing to do with mine (pointers to members are not regular pointers at all), so your theory is still a specualtion.

Comment: yes your PackArray getting passed nullptr makes your code break.  The types of the things packed must match the types of the extracted exactly (or be binary compatible), and they must be trivial and of the same size.  sizeof nullptr is probably 1, sizeof void ptr is going to be 4 or 8.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont sizeof nullptr is usually sizeof a pointer for some reason, even though it's not a pointer https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GKWfs6 . I am not sure why this is the case honestly.